# TikZ coding style

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I've got a piece of TikZ code here and since I am only starting to learn how to use it, I wanted to ask whether this code would be regarded to be ok or rather completely unreadable and what I can do to improve it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
every picture/.prefix style={
execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{"}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newdimen\field
\def\white{white}
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 7}
    \foreach \y in {0, ..., 7} {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "white" : "black"}
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{int(round(56+\x-8*\y))}
        \edef\field{\pgfmathresult}
        \edef\textcolor{\ifx\color\white black\else white\fi}
        \path[fill=\color] (\x, \y) rectangle ++ (1, 1) node[color=\textcolor, pos=.5] {
            \Large
            \ifnum \field < 8
                \pgfmathparse{2^(\field)}
                \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
            \else
                \dots
            \fi
        };
    }
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, 8) -- (8, 8) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code outputs a demonstration of the [Wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem).

Comment: Don't use `\color` and `\textcolor` for the checks, because they are important macros; it's true that the redefinitions are in a group, but one never knows and you might use the original ones in the text, maybe hidden in some macro.

Comment: Should this not be on [codereview.SE]?

Comment: I think Code Review is there for programming languages that don't have their own site.

Comment: @Raphael Whenever I feel the urge to share my Latex code for general feedback rather than to solve a specific problem, I wonder whether Latex code review questions are on topic here. But my sharing and please-criticise-my-code mood usually passes long before I ask the question on meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd avoid using `\color` and `\textcolor` which are important macros in the `color` and `xcolor` packages: you might end up in using them, buried in other macros, when typesetting the text of a node.

Also some constructions can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 7}
  \foreach \y in {0, ..., 7} {
    \ifodd\numexpr\x+\y\relax
      \def\bgcolor{white}\def\fgcolor{black}
    \else
      \def\bgcolor{black}\def\fgcolor{white}
    \fi
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\field{int(round(56+\x-8*\y))}
  \path[fill=\bgcolor] (\x, \y) rectangle ++ (1, 1) node[color=\fgcolor, pos=.5] {
     \Large
     \ifnum \field < 8
       \pgfmathparse{2^(\field)}%
       \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
     \else
       \dots
     \fi
  };
}
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, 8) -- (8, 8) -- (8, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Declaring `\newdimen\field` is wrong in two ways:

1. the declaration must go *outside* the loops, or you'd do it at every cycle, wasting a register each time;
2. you then use `\edef\field`, so overriding the meaning just given to it as a register name.

[image]

Comment: With this, I get "Missing = inserted for \ifnum". It seems that \field is not interpreted as an integer in that context (I ran into that problem earlier).

Comment: I removed the `shorthandoff` declaration as `babel` is not used in the example. Are you perhaps using Spanish `babel`?

Comment: @egreg: No, German polyglossia.

Comment: @percusse I get an integer, but probably it's better to use that command anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a very simple TikZ version (I use named styles to choose between black or white) :

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  square/.style={draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0},
  square 0/.style={square,fill=black},
  square 1/.style={square,fill=white},
  % 
  label/.style={font=\large,align=center,text depth=.3cm,text height=.7cm},
  label 0/.style={label,text=white},
  label 1/.style={label,text=black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, ..., 7} {
    \foreach \y in {0, ..., 7} {
      % black or white square
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\square{mod(\x+\y,2)}
      \node[square \square] at (\x,\y) {};
      % label
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\field{int(56+\x-8*\y)}
      \ifnum \field < 8 
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\power{2^(\field)}
      \else%
        \def\power{\dots}%
      \fi%
      \node[label \square]  at (\x,\y) {\power};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Some number printing fun :) Since there are huge numbers let `fpu` handle them. I used truncated [.]illionths

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu,babel}%TikZ 3 has a babel library that takes care of active chars
\pgfkeys{
/pgf/number format/mynum/.style={1000 sep={},std=0:3,sci precision=0,
    sci generic={mantissa sep={\!\cdot},exponent={\scriptstyle {10}^{##1}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0, ..., 7} {
    \foreach \y in {0, ..., 7} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolor{mod(\x+\y,2) ? 100 : 0}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\field{56+\x-8*\y}
    \path[fill=black!\mycolor] (\x, \y) rectangle ++ (1, 1) 
    \pgfextra{\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{2^(\field)}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}}
        node[text=white!\mycolor!black, midway] {
           \pgfmathprintnumber[mynum]{\pgfmathresult}
        };
    }
}
\draw (0, 0) rectangle (8, 8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]